# Getting "getters()" into an array() from parent class (PHP and ZF1)

Tags: php, entity-framework, oop, zend-framework

I may be having a basic OOP doubt but I believe it's worth sharing after hours of search.

For example: From my controller I want to retrieve data from an Entity Class... however, this class extends an Abstract that MAY do the job.
Controller:

```
//Setting info to object
$entity->setName( 'Peter' );
$entity->setAnge( 33 );

//Retriving data in array
$data = $entity->getData();
```

Class Entity:

```
class Entity extends EntityAbstract {
    private $name;
    private $age;

    public function getData() {
      return parent::getData($this);//I'm passing this object to get its methods (or vars)
    }

    public class setName() { ... }
    public class getName() { ... }
    public class setAge() { ... }
    public class getAge() { ... }
}
```

And finally Abrastract Class (Parent).

```
class EntityAbstract {

    public function getData( $entity ) {
        //I'm not sure how to proceed here.
        //I've listed all child's methods, but can't list class_vars (private)
        $methods = get_class_methods( $entity );

        // By listing method, I've tryed to use a regular expression to
        // identify methods starting with 'get' and then setting an array but
        // this didn't work... I got a memory exceed error. 
        $data = array();
        // foreach() loop
        $data[ $valueKey ] = $entity->$methodGetOfEach();

        return $data;
    }
}
```

If perhaps there's some zend method to help me with this, but I believe this is a matter of OOP and PHP knowledge to solve.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but out of a few things that are strange, trying to define a class inside a class as getters and setters...?

Anyway, why don't you do something like:

```
class Entity {

    protected $name;
    protected $age;

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getAge() {
        return $this->age;
    }
    public function setAge($age) {
        $this->age = intval($age);
    }

    public function toArray() {
            return = array(
                   $this->name,
                   $this->age
            );
    }
}
```

You could then do something like:

```
$entity = new Entity();

$entity->setName( 'Peter' );
$entity->setAge( 33 );

//Retriving data in array
$data = $entity->toArray();
```

**Update:**

Ah, now I get what you want to do.

You could achieve this the following way:

```
class EntityBase {

    protected $name;

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function toArray() {
            return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}

class EntityExtend extends EntityBase {
    protected $age;

    public function getAge() {
        return $this->age;
    }
    public function setAge($age) {
        $this->age = intval($age);
    }
}

$entity = new EntityExtend();

$entity->setName( 'Peter' );
$entity->setAge( 33 );

//Retriving data in array
$data = $entity->toArray();

print_r($data);
```

It hasn't got anything to do with an actual abstract class type though. The magic of OOP.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help... For sure this would work. I was actually trying is NOT having to create a toArray (or getData) method every Entity class I create.

Based on what I'm thinking, I could create new Entities Classes extending EntityAbstract and only setting its attributes and generationg getters and setters. That's all. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Dave for you time. In this case I'll have to change my Entity vars from private to protected. That's fine. Thanks very much.

Comment: Glad I could help. And be aware: if you wanted vars in extended classes not to parsed by toArray(), you would only have to define them as private.